# where an internal dispatch table. in addTarget:action:forControlEvents:

Tags: iphone, uiapplication, uicontrol

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIControl

addTarget:action:forControlEvents:
Adds a target and action for a particular event (or events) to an internal dispatch table.

I can't underStand the dispatch table.

the table in UIControl  or UIApplication  or other place ???

Answer (score 1):

from "Programming iOS 5 by Matt Neuburg (O'Reilly)"

> A control maintains an internal dispatch table: for each control event
>   there is some number of  target-action pairs, of which the *action* is
>   a selector (the name of a method) and the *target* is the object to
>   which that message is to be sent. When a control event occurs, the
>   control consults its dispatch table, finds all the targer-action pairs
>   associated with that control event, and sends each action message to
>   the corresponding target.

[image]